# jQuery - dynamically changing CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to dynamically change the CSS for a specific element.
The following hard coded jQuery statement works:

```
$('.people div[data-face="1"] i').css('background-image', 'url(http://localhost:58888/_pictures/picture_000.jpg)');
```

However, I need "1" to be a variable ("dataNum") and the actual url needs to be a variable called "URL".

I've been trying various escape characters, but can't get it to work without errors.
Here's my latest:

```
 $("\'.people div[data-face=\" " + dataNum + '\"] i\').css(\'background-image\', \'url(' + URL + ')\' ');
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with string concatenation like:

```
$('.people div[data-face="' + dataNum + '"] i').css('background-image', 'url('+URL+')');
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery selectors are not magic; they're just ordinary strings.
You don't need to escape anything.

Instead, you just need ordinary string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.people div[data-face="'+dataNum+'"] i').css('background-image', 'url(\''+URL+'\')');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just string math (concatenation) for dataNum and a straight substitution for the url variable:

```
$('.people div[data-face="' + dataNum + '"] i').css('background-image', url);
```

or if you want to see the string math broken down in more detail:

```
var selector = '.people div[data-face="';
selector += dataNum;
selector += '"] i';
$(selector).css('background-image', url);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.people div[data-face="' + dataNum + "'"] i').css('background-image', 'url(' + URL + ')');
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not really need escaping, following code should work:

```
$('.people div[data-face="'+dataNum+'"] i').css('background-image', 'url('+URL+')');
```